# Animated gif in PS only shows first frame

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

So I have a series of images that I am trying to make into an animated gif. I have an animation time line and all that basic jazz, and I have saved for the web as a gif.

When I reach the final save menu, I only get the option for html and images. The html setting shows the animation in sequence but cannot be uploaded to my webpage with out only being the first image of the animation with no action at all. The image setting just shows all the images in separate documents.

What is up with this thing?

Comment: Here is a link to a possible solution. http://www.stoneleighphotography.com/making-a-gif-in-cs6-photoshop/

Answer (score 1):

When creating your animation I always set my main image as the first and last frame.

In save for web window, click Preset Gif 128 Dithered / then at the bottom where it says animation choose the Looping Option: Once or Forever / Then I always simply save as image only.

Add to you website like this:
`<img src="youfilepath/image-name.gif">`

Hope this helps.